# Add indexed array to localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, local-storage

How I could add this indexed array `names`, to `localStorage`. And call this element:

```
var name= new Array();

for( var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++ ) {
    names[results.rows.item(i).IdTypePrestation ] = results.rows.item(i).LibellePrestation;
}
```

If I change this line:

```
names[results.rows.item(i).IdTypePrestation] = results.rows.item(i).LibellePrestation;
```

To this:

```
names[i] = results.rows.item(i).LibellePrestation;
```

Everything is ok, but I need the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Set to `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.someArrayValue = JSON.stringify(myArray);
```

Get from `localStorage`:

```
myArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.someArrayValue);
```

Comment: `localStorage['names']=JSON.stringify(name);`

Comment: @B.M.A: How does that not work? What does it do, and what you you need / want it to do?

Comment: i want to add this tab `names` to my localstorage, but when i call element like this`
`var j=results.rows.item(0).IdTypePrestation;  var retrievedObject1 = JSON.parse(localStorage['tableau_type']);  alert(retrievedObject1 [j])` return undifined

Comment: have you set `'tableau_type'` in the `localStorage`, before doing: `JSON.parse(localStorage['tableau_type']);`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution should look like this:

```
//Set names on tableau_type line of localStorage
localStorage['tableau_type'] = JSON.stringify(names);

//Get all names on tableau_type line of localStorage
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage['tableau_type']);
$.each(retrievedObject ,function(index,element){
    alert(element);
});
```